# Hide window title bar in pygtk

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I'm trying to get a window with border decoration but without title bar in GTK using python

I think this can be done in QT with

```
QMainWindow(parent, Qt::FramelessWindowHint),
```

The set_decorated to false doesn't fit my needs because I also need the regular border around the window.

I get to know GDK Constants and GDK WM Decoration. But I'm completely lost

I also found this sentence in vala language but I don't know how to do it in pygtk

```
this.get_window().set_decorations(Gdk.WMDecoration.BORDER);
```

Any help would be much appreciate

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using

```
self.get_window().set_decorations(Gdk.WMDecoration.BORDER)
```

after show_all() solved my problem